# Vaadin annotation @Route not detected (Ubuntu bug?)

Tags: ubuntu, annotations, vaadin

Trying some code using vaadin, this annotation @Route is not recognised at any time. I have used Eclipse and IntelliJ, but the same problem in both IDEs. Tha is under Ubuntu however in Windows I found no problem! Thanks...
Here is the proof in Intellij (similar in Eclipse)

No suggestions for route img

[image: 1]

Comment: What do you mean by "not detected"? Does it compile and run?  Are the routes not picked up when visiting in the browser?

Comment: How does your pom.xml look like? Can you share your project?